# Postgres suddenly raise error '/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file)

Tags: python, django, postgresql, macos

when I run Django project or any code related to Postgres :

```
Referenced from: '/Users/mahmoudnasser/.local/share/virtualenvs/wyspp_backend-PwdII1PB/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so'
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file)
```

I tried many solutions online but none of them worked.

**Note**: I use **MacOS**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To solve this problem just run the following command:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib && sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib
```

Comment: This wasn't the complete solution for me, BUT, it did make me think about re-installing the pip dependencies in hopes that the linking would resolve itself, and it did. See answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/73874970/1267549

Comment: This command did not work for me. I think it was due to the author having a different brew prefix to what I have.

The following command, which is brew prefix agnostic did work for me.

`mkdir -p /usr/local/lib && sudo ln -s $(brew --prefix)/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib
`

Comment: This also works with my rust project (diesel + postgres) on Mac mini `ln -s /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib /opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib`

Answer (score 26):

I have just encountered with this problem after upgrade Postgres with homwbrew.
So I try to reinstall psycopg2 in my venv and that's solve it.
Now it's ok. Just try:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall psycopg2
```

Comment: This solution worked for me because I had installed Homebrew's formulae `postgresql@14` instead of `postgresql` so the path that psycopg2 was trying to find `libpq.5.dylib` was `/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib` instead of `/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql@14/lib/postgresql@14/libpq.5.dylib`.

Answer (score 2):

Something similar happened to me following a `brew` PostgreSQL upgrade. The solution to my problem was to delete my virtual environment, in my case `.venv`, and rerun:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

After that, I was able to start my application with no problem.

I think the issue was the result of an outdated dependency graph. Re-installing the dependencies with pip found the new version of Postgres and linked the `libpq.5.dylib` correctly.

Note, I was using the following `psycopg2` dependency:

```
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
```

For what it's worth, I am also on `MacOS Monterey` and this just happened in a second codebase on the same machine.

The exact error was:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/username/dev/src/project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: '/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib'
Referenced from: '/Users/username/dev/src/project/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-310-darwin.so'
Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/postgresql@14/14.5_4/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file)
```